# find a specific set of characters in the middle of any other characters, except a specific word

Tags: regex

I'm having a regex issue. I'm trying to find a specific set of characters (`rms` case insensitive) in the middle of any word.

The problem we found was this would return on anything like `formShow` or `forms`. So we tried to write some regex to narrow the search down a bit.

Checking other questions on stackoverflow I created the below:

```
^(?!.*forms).*rms.*$
```

However this doesnt seem to match any of the test examples we came up with.

```
rms (should match)
RMS (should match)
rMs (should match)
forms (should not match)
tfrmrmsexport (should match)
formshow (should not match)
```

How can I limit our searches to anything with rms in it, but exclude anything that has `forms` in it?

Comment: @ctwheels this works! thank you so much! If you make this an actual answer I'll mark it as the correct one.

Comment: or `\b\w*(?<!fo)rms\w*` which is a little bit more performant (but less maintainable if you have to add other words to exclude)

Comment: @Kynian moved to answer. I've also simplified it a little to improve performance.

Comment: @Aaron If it's ok with you, I've added your solution to my alternatives. I'll remove it if you prefer I don't include it in my answer, please let me know if that's the case.

Comment: @ctwheels sure, thanks for the credit and even bothering to ask !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Code

All regular expression patterns below use the `i` (case-insensitive) flag.

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/LTRlj3/3)

```
\b(?!\w*forms)\w*rms\w*
```

Alternatives:

```
\b(?:(?!forms)\w)*rms\w*
\b\w*(?<!fo)rms\w*           #As proposed by Aaron in comments beneath the question
```

<sub>[Link to Aaron's user profile here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1678362/aaron)</sub>

---

### Explanation

- `\b` Assert position as a word boundary
- `(?!\w*forms)` Negative lookahead ensuring `forms` doesn't exist in the word
- `\w*` Match any number of word characters
- `rms` Match this literally
- `\w*` Match any number of word characters

Answer (score 0):

Or, the more complex form if looking for rms in the middle of whitespaced
bounded groups of letters.

This will give better results, because a *word* `\w` is just a character class
which should not be confused by the definition of a word in language.

`(?i)(?<!\S)(?:(?!forms)\S)*rms(?:(?!forms)\S)*(?!\S)`

Formatted

```
 (?i)                          # Case insensitive modifier
 (?<! \S )                     # Whitespace boundary
 (?:                           # Before 'rms'
      (?! forms )                   # Not 'forms' ahead 
      \S                            # Non-whitespace char
 )*                            # 0 to many times

 rms                           # The 'rms' we need

 (?:                           # After 'rms'
      (?! forms )                   # Not 'forms' ahead 
      \S                            # Non-whitespace char
 )*                            # 0 to many times
 (?! \S )                      # Whitespace boundary
```